# Swift Pass data between files

Tags: ios, swift

I need to pass a variable value from a file to another file. 
 I try this code but it doesn't working, on the destination data the value it's `nil` :

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     var destView: OtpVC = segue.destinationViewController as! OtpVC
     destView.dataPassed = "\(mobile)"
}
```

`OtpVC` is the destination ViewController and mobile is the variable I want to transport to the `OtpVC` View.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing something wrong somewhere.

If you are pushing/presenting the next `OtpVC` programatically, `prepareForSegue` will not be called and therefore `destView.dataPassed` will be `nil`. `prepareForSegue` only works if you define your view controller transitions in a storyboard, or call `performSegue` in code to do the transition.

For example, pushing:

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
    let nextScreen = OtpVC()
    nextScreen.dataPassed = "\(mobile)"
    navigation.pushViewController(nextScreen)
}
```

Or presenting:

```
let nextScreen = OtpVC()
nextScreen.dataPassed = "\(mobile)"
self.presentViewController(nextScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: oh, so if i don't have a preformsegue i just put var destView: OtpVC = segue.destinationViewController as! OtpVC
            destView.dataPassed = "\(mobile)" ??

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I doubt if you want to set it to "\(mobile)" though. That converts whatever mobile contains to a String object. If it' already a string it doesn't do anything, and if it's not a string the original type of the object is lost as it's passed.

Comment: @VaultDesign If you don't have a perform segue, add the segue to your storyboard. :) You can simply Google how if you're new to all this. If you're not using storyboards, you need to call `performSegue` somewhere.